# Search button on website won't click VBA

Tags: html, vba, click

I am trying to insert data into a search field and then click the search button. I tried `getElementsByid("SiteSearchForm_SearchBtn")(0).Click` and `getElementsByclassname("searchBtn")(0).Click`.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="searchBtn"><a href="#search" id="SiteSearchForm_SearchBtn">Search</a></div>
```

**VBA CODE**:

```
With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate URL_1
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
        Loop

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("hint hint-search")(0).Value = "Eliroyal2$"
            IE.Document.getElementsByid("SiteSearchForm_SearchBtn")(0).submit

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

End With
```

Comment: put the 0 in square brackets and try thatfro the get elements by class.`("hint hint_search")[0]` and no zero for the elem by id edited for the fourth time....take the s off getElementById and make the I capital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having the URL, I would say that the reason why this line of code cannot work:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByid("SiteSearchForm_SearchBtn")(0).submit
```

is two-folded.

**1)** It's `getElementById`, not `Elements`;

**2)** The function returns a single element, so you don't need to access a collection with `(0)`

If you are sure about your ID, just try:

```
IE.Document.getElementByid("SiteSearchForm_SearchBtn").Click
```

...otherwise please provide us with the URL for us to troubleshooting.

**EDIT**

According to the HTML line you provided, you cannot get the element by class name simply because the element you get is a `<div>` element, which doesn't support the Click event. 
By default, in fact, the div does not have the property `cursor:pointer` because it is thought as a "container". The link, i.e. `<a>`, is instead a clickable element by default which redirects you to the `href` address (where you want to go).

As for the line setting up the value of the search field, instead, it seems to be fine. But are you sure you cannot go by a unique property (such as an `id`) to avoid a change in the CSS naming of the website might turn into a crash of your code in the future?